# Responsive layout for two divs one with fixed length in a row

Tags: jquery, html, css

- I have two divs
- One with fixed width 20px;
- I want second div to take all available remaining width of its parent container
- I dont know the width in px of parent container. I have it in '%s'

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: just give second div width auto

Comment: For second div, If I give auto its does not work, if I give 100% I get horizontal scroll bar

Comment: try the `width:Auto;` and add a margin-sideOfFixedDiv: 21px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need javascript to do this, nor as much css as the others were posting; making what this guy needs way over-complicated:

HTML

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='first'/>
       &nbsp;
     </div>
    <div id='second'/>
       second
     </div>    
</div>
```

​
CSS

```
#first {
   width: 20px;
   float: left;
}
```

The non-floated div will assume the rest of the width of the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/thundercracker/MpPLr/28/

Comment: In the fiddle or when applying it to your page? What browser?

Comment: could you replicate a js fiddle of your code that is causing the horz scroll?

Comment: Your fiddle works. When I write my code in fiddle, it works. No horizontal scroll. However, in my FF it breaks. I will look into more. Please check my updates until tomorrow. I will definitely update.

Comment: I think I was dealing with this problem http://jsfiddle.net/yJdbF/3/. You are/were right. Thx much!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Make the width of the second div `100%` or `auto` and remove the first div's width via its margin. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dAryP/

Comment: Quick question: Does not 100% means "100% width of parent"?...so it will become 100% + 20px width at display time??

Comment: For second div, If I give auto its does not work, if I give 100% I get horizontal scroll bar

Comment: You're right, sorry. A work-around though: place the first div within the second div. In the meantime, I'll look for a CSS-only method alternative.

Comment: In your soln...if I make #conatiner width from 90 -> 100%...I get horizonatl scroll bar...is that expected??

Comment: Seems like the only way is to hide the overflow. It works, but it's slighty hacky and may not be the best coding practice. Whatever the case: http://jsfiddle.net/dAryP/

If that's what you need, then all the better. Expanding the container makes sense, but I can't see it expanding to the length instead using just CSS. If you need an alternative, just use my aforementioned work-around. Give this a shot though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='first'/>
       first
    </div>
    <div id='second'/>
       second
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#first {
   width: 20px;
   height:50px; // height is set for test
   background-color: red    
}

#second {
   height:50px;
   background-color: blue;
}

#wrapper div {
   float:left
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   var r = $('#wrapper').width() - 20;
   $('#second').width(r)
}).resize()
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MpPLr/)

Comment: code rulez, you don't have to visually validate (and fix) your design across 4 operating systems, 7 browsers as with css. But I sure would be interested in seeing a cross browser css solution if it exists :)

Comment: Do doing this via code is recommended? Is this a correct approach/answer?...looking for some feedback from experts me being *new*

Comment: @gauravjain It depends, if the parent element's width is fixed you can set fixed width, this solution works in every browser and I used jQuery as the question has a tag of it.

Comment: Sure...thx...I would love to do it via code if that is how it should be done...I just want to do it right....thx again